# How can i export data to PDF from an SQL query?

Tags: files

Given the following code:

```
$query3 = db_select('1_jp_lomba', 'jp2')->fields('jp2', array('nama_lomba'));
$query3->condition('jp2.jp_ke',$selected,'=');
$options4 = $query3->execute()->fetchCol();
```

How can I export the data held in the `$options4` variable to a PDF, using Drupal 7? Is there any existing API function that will help me with this?

Comment: No there is no internal function that supports export to pdf.

Comment: so what should i use? did fpdf works in drupal 7?

Comment: fpdf is an external library probably the most common. And it can be use with D7. Refer http://drupal.org/project/print to see how they implement or is it possible to use the module.